# GmailApp.sendEmail 'from' option stopped working

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api, google-sheets-api

As of yesterday, Nov 10th 2016, my google script stopped working with the following error msg.:

> Invalid argument: info@mydomain.ch (line 168, file "Code")

The line in question looks like this:

```
GmailApp.sendEmail("someone@theirdomain.com",
  "Subject title",
            "", {
            from: "mrbob@mydomain.com",
            name: "Mr. Bob",
            htmlBody:
                "Hello, <br><br> Bla blah blah... <br> Cheers,<br> Mr. Bob" 
});
```

My email address (mrbob@mydomain.com) is set up to 'send mail as' in my gmail account. It is not an alias. The function in my code has been working well for the past year, so I don't know why it has suddenly stopped. Any ideas and solutions? 
It's quite important that the from address be this one rather than my gmail address.

Comment: Remove advanced parameters in the options object until the error goes away, as a way to troubleshoot the exact origin of the error.  Use trial and error, but in a systematic way.

Answer (score 3):

Google has recently made some changes in the MailApp / GmailApp service and you can now only send emails from accounts that are set as "aliases" in your main Gmail account.

Go to Gmail -> Settings -> Accounts and ensure that "set as alias" is written against the email address that you are using to send emails in the Google Script.

Answer (score 1):

as of today (June 2017) The opposite of Karl_S response worked for me. I was using MailApp.sendmail(...)

I changed to

```
GmailApp.sendEmail('to@email.com', 'subject', 'message', {'from':'aliasinmyGmailaccount@otherdomain.com'})
```

and it worked.

this is the current documentation:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)

Answer (score 0):

Try running the code from the editor with either the Run or Debug menu item.  I have recently had a few scripts that have needed me to re-accept permissions.  I have not looked into it to see if additional access is needed.

My emails are sending with this:

```
MailApp.sendEmail({
     to: sendToEmailAddress,
     bcc: emailAddressCC,
     replyTo: emailAddressReplyTo,
     name: emailFromName,
     subject: emailSubjectText,
     body: emailText,
     htmlBody: emailHTMLBody
   });
```

Can you try the [MailApp class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app) instead.  From the documentation page:

> This service allows users to send emails with complete control over
>   the content of the email. Unlike GmailApp, MailApp's sole purpose is
>   sending email. MailApp cannot access a user's Gmail inbox.
>
> Changes to scripts written using GmailApp are more likely to trigger a
>   re-authorization request from a user than MailApp scripts.

Comment: Thanks for tip. It was the first thing I tried. It didn't require any re-accepting of permissions.

Comment: Added suggestion of the use of MailApp in place of Gmail App class.